# Remove vertical spacing between two figures side by side, each with its own caption

Tags: spacing, captions, minipage, vertical-spacing, sidebyside

Maybe it is a duplicate question, but I've tried more than 6 codes and didn't get the desired result. I need to remove the vertical spacing between two side-by-side figures and also the spacing between captions and the figures like this:
[image]

I'm using the latex template of this joural
https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/turkish-journal-of-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/qbbtnbyqvtmm

This is my code

```
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=12.0cm]{Figure 7}
        \caption{Power Angle.}
        \label{fig:7}
    \end{minipage}\hfill %
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{Figure 8.pdf}
        \caption{Rotor speed.}
        \label{fig:8}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Both Figures 7 and 8 are available here https://ufile.io/f/oe1k3
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are whitespaces around your images. Remove those and everything should be fine.

Comment: Another point: if possible import image in eps format. Then you won't have those whitespaces. Usually while making PDF, full pages are used and thus those whitespaces appear.

Comment: Thanks @Imran for the reply, i got a message error  when i import the eps files, i'll crop the pdf files and see.

Comment: SOLVED BY CROPPING THE PDF FILES, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, you may take a look at the `subcaption` package which makes it possible to add subfigures.

Comment: Will do @Imran, i appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132162/discussion-between-koko-lolo-and-imran).